# How to get all views in hierarchy in my touch position - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to get all UIViews at my touch position?

In image below I need to get all UIViews in touches with the yellow line.

**Snippet from UI hierarchy:**

[image]

I looking for a similar function to SpriteKit where we use to get all nodes at point with

```
self.nodes(at: touch.location(in: self))
```

Comment: If you are looking for UIViews then you should probably tag this with UIKit, not SpriteKit

Answer (score 7):

You have to traverse all views in the hierachy like:

```
extension UIView {
    func allViews(for touch: UITouch) -> [UIView] {
        return self.allViews(at: touch.location(in: self))
    }

    func allViews(at point: CGPoint) -> [UIView] {
        var stack = [UIView]()
        var result = [UIView]()

        stack.append(self)
        while let view = stack.popLast() {
            let localPoint = view.convert(point, from: self)

            if view.bounds.contains(localPoint) {
                result.append(view)
            }
            stack.append(contentsOf: view.subviews)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

You can either start with any super view which contains all appropriate views (e.g the view of a view controller) or the window. The point for the second method must be relative to the bounds of the view which is represented by `self`.

Comment: why that break statement means to never happen?

Comment: @Saranjith: The while loop will onlybe entered when the stack is not empty. Thus, `stack.popLast()` should always return a view.

Comment: @clemens Then force unwrap `stack.popLast()` or use `while let view = stack.popLast()` to begin with.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr: Thanks, nice hint. I've adapted my post.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in two steps:

1. get all views starting from a certain view

   ```
   func descendants(of view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
       return view.subviews + view.subviews.flatMap(descendants(of:))
   }
   ```
2. filter the view that contain the touch point:

   ```
   let touchLocation = touchGesture.location(in: nil)
   let matchingViews = descendants(of: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!)
       .filter { $0.convert($0.bounds, to: nil).contains(touchLocation) }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In UIKit the responder chain works like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain), I think there is no way getting all the list, because it a touch "goes" until a responder catches it and not further.

Answer (score 0):

```
func subviewsThatContain(point: CGPoint, in view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    var views = [UIView]()

    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview.frame.contains(subview.convert(point, from: self.view)) {
            views.append(subview)
        }

        views += subviewsThatContain(point: point, in: subview)
    }

    return views
}
```

and function call look like this

```
var allViews = [self.view] + subviewsThatContain(in: self.view, point: touch.location(in: self.view))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use hittest to check all view hierarchies

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let point = targetPoint,
            var view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
                return
        }
        var views: [UIView] = [view]
        while view != nil {
            view = view.hitTest(point, with: event)
            if view != nil {
                views.append(view!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work in every case, because `hitTest()` needs a point  relative to the bounds of the view. It will not find views which are covered by another view. It may also contain an infinite loop because `hitTest()` may return the view itself.